# MultiPart Upload Image Progress on Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display upload progress on my Android Client using a way mentioned below

```
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(){
                @Override
                public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
                    super.writeTo(new UploadOutputStream(outstream,listener));
                }

            };

public class UploadOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {

private final ProgressListener listener;
private long transferred;

public UploadOutputStream(final OutputStream out, final ProgressListener listener)
{
    super(out);
    this.listener = listener;
    this.transferred = 0;
}

public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException
{
    out.write(b, off, len);
    this.transferred += len;
    this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
}

public void write(int b) throws IOException
{
    out.write(b);
    this.transferred++;
    this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
}



}
```

I am adding image to multipart ByteArrayBody as below

```
reqEntity.addPart("image", bab);
```

The problem is that I see the progress update only when the whole image has been uploaded.
I want the progress when chunks are being uploaded.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Many Thanks

Manan

Comment: Can anybody direct me to a tutorial on how MultiPart works under the hood i.e. how the file is uploaded as chunks of Bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem was because I was using ByteArrayBody that does NOT send the file in chunks instead writes the whole stream at once.
Used FileBody to resolve the Issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a problem with multipart encoding. Most likely, the HTTP client is optimizing the writing by sending a single `write()` call, since it knows the size and it fits in its buffers. This call most likely blocks and your listener is executed immediately after that.

You can split that `out.write(b, off, len)` call into multiple smaller calls, at the slight expense of speed.

Comment: But my file is more than 1MB. Do you think in that case also HTTP Client will write it in single write() call

Comment: It's easy to check - set a breakpoint at `out.write(b, off, len);` and take a look at the byte array size, off and len.

Alternatively, you could just be displaying the byte count wrong - are you calculating percentages correctly? Your listener is receiving the number of bytes transmitted..

Comment: Thanks Delyan. I am NOT even trying %ge. I tried getting the bytes transferred. I have two parts in MultiPart. One is json and other is image. For JSON I see the bytes as they are transferred but for image it comes back only when the whole image is uploaded. The only difference is json is being sent as StringBody and image as a BysteArryBody. NOT sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. A ByteArrayEntity contains the entire content. (Try uploading a 20-30M file, your app should crash without `largeHeap`). [The source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/apache-http/+/master/src/org/apache/http/entity/ByteArrayEntity.java) says that it just calls `write(byte[])` on the stream , which in turn [calls](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/heads/master/luni/src/main/java/java/io/OutputStream.java) `write(buffer, 0, buffer.length)`. Mystery solved.